# Copy rows between tables when doesn't exist in target, but manipulate 1 value

Tags: mysql

I've got 2 tables `"TEST"` and `"TEST2"`, they are the `same format` and have some 50 columns, extract below :

```
Column1 (uniqueidentifier) ; Column2 ; Column3 ; UpdateSource
```

Column1 is a unique identifier.

I want to insert any row into table TEST2 that is in TEST, but not yet in TEST2 (based on Column1 as the unique identifier). I can do this fine with the code below:

```
insert into test2 
select test.* 
from test 
left join test2 on test.column1 = test2.column1 
where test2.column1 is null;
```

However, when creating the new row in TEST2 I would like to fill field UPDATESOURCE with a fixed value ie. UPDATESOURCE='SCRIPT A' for all rows created in TEST2 by this script.

How do I specify the fixed value in the query above - or do I need to rewrite the query?

As UPDATESOURCE is empty in TEST, I can remove the field from this table only, if it makes a difference, but I need to set UPDATESOURCE in TEST2 do a different value in different scripts, so can't simply use a default value setting for this field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly list the columns in the `insert` statement.  Then you can manipulate them one at a time:

```
insert into test2(<list of all columns>)
    select <list of all columns except update source>, 'Script A' as UpdateSource
    from test left join
         test2
         on test.column1 = test2.column1
    where test2.column1 is null;
```

To get the list, you can use:

```
select group_concat(column_name separator ', ')
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'test2';
```

Comment: Thank you. As I have a lot of columns, I was trying to avoid listing them explicitly - but I see this is not an option now, so your advice above (including how to generate the column list quickly) is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the columns that you want to insert explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO test2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, UpdateSource)
SELECT test.Column1, test.Column2, test.Column3, 'SCRIPT A'
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you. As I have a lot of columns, I was trying to avoid listing them explicitly - but I see this is not an option now.

Answer (score 0):

Check simple insert statement syntax - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

```
INSERT INTO TBALE2 (COL1, COL2, COL3, ..., COLN, UPDATESOURCE) VALUES 
SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, a.COL3, ..., a.COLN, 'SCRIPT A'
FROM TEST a
LFET JOIN TEST2 b ON a.COL1 = b.COL2 
WHERE a.COL1 IS NULL;
```

Hope this helps.